# Making Azure Functions working with .NET 7.x and Azure Functions Runtime 4.x

Tags: azure-functions, .net-7.0

I originally created a .NET Core 3.1 version of the `Azure Function` project a year ago. It was upgraded to .NET 6.0 and now wants to upgrade to .NET 7.0.

I tried to create an `Azure Function` project in `Visual Studio 2022`, but see only `isolated worker process` option. Does `Azure Function` work in `dotnet` mode?

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to create an Azure Function project in Visual Studio 2022, but see only isolated worker process option. Does Azure Function work in dotnet mode?

If you want to develop using **.Net 7** you are bound to **isolated worker process** Azure Functions as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v4%2Ccmd#supported-versions):

[image]